# Connection string settings not available (tracking.contact)

Tags: xdb

I am getting below error in my sitecore application.

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Connection string
>   settings not available (tracking.contact) Source:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDriver.FromConnectionString(String
>   connectionStringName)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.MongoDb.ProcessingPool.MongoDbProcessingPool..ctor(String
>   connectionStringName)

Steps I did so far:

I verified the connection string seems no issue with that.
Verified my mongodb port settings as well as mongodb is running

Any one can help with the issue I am facing?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share the connectionstring entries..

Comment: What is the Sitecore version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, that you have

```
<add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://..."/>
```

in your ConnectionStrings.config. If yes - check next:

1) Try to connect with this "mongodb://..." connectionstring to collection by using RoboMongo or any other UI software and check that collections are really exist in mongodb.

2) Check versions of Sitecore and MongoDB that you use:

- Sitecore 8 Update 5 supports MongoDB 3.0
- older Sitecore versions support  MongoDB 2.6.x and MongoDB.Driver.dll version 1.8.3.9

Tip: you can immitate this error by checking your connection programmatically:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tracking.contact"].ToString();
try
{
  var driver = MongoDbDriver.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // debug here if exception throw
}
```

Comment: tracking.contact is missing in my CM config, now it is working